# prolog,using the right algorithm but getting the wrong answer

Tags: prolog

i am trying to find the maximum number out of a list and even used write() for every recursion to verify my steps.here is my code

```
max(A,R):-
    maxx(A,1,R).

maxx([],R,R).
maxx([H|T],B,C):-
    (   H > B
    ->  C is H
    ;   C is B
    ),
    write(' maximmum of'),
    write(C),
    maxx(T,C,R1).
```

and it gives me this output when I run it with question max([3,2,4,1],A).

```
maximmum is 3 maximmum is 3 maximmum is 4 maximmum is 4

A = 3.
```

but A should be 4 not 3,so can any one tell me where I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this clause:

```
maxx([H|T],B,C):-
    (   H > B
    ->  C is H
    ;   C is B
    ),
    write(' maximmum of'),
    write(C),
    maxx(T,C,R1).
```

I suppose you are seeing a singleton warning for `R1`. That's because `R1` is the real result you need but you are ignoring it and, instead, your clause is "returning" `C`, which is your intermediate result. You can fix this by returning the final result:

```
maxx([H|T], B, R):-
    (   H > B
    ->  C is H
    ;   C is B
    ),
    write(' maximmum of'),
    write(C),
    maxx(T, C, R).   % R is the final result that you want, not C
```

As an aside, you don't want to use `is/2` to equate (unify) two variables in Prolog. `is/2` is for arithmetic expression evaluation and assignment. Instead, use `=/2` for unification:

```
maxx([H|T], B, R):-
    (   H > B
    ->  C = H
    ;   C = B
    ),
    write(' maximmum of'),
    write(C),
    maxx(T, C, R).   % R is the final result that you want, not C
```